# Tracking Gearman Worker based on the workload Parameter

Tags: php, gearman, messagebroker

I am new to Gearman and I am using it in an email setting. We are sending email campaigns using Gearman. So we create a campaigns (divided in batches sent every x minutes) and we assign those campaigns to worker that dispatches the batches to the SMTP server. So 1 campaign to 1 Worker... When debugging (In the case of multiple of multiple campaigns so multiple workers) I cant figure out which worker is handling which campaign ID.
I hope this was clear.... Thanks in advance

Comment: answered in forum https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gearman/Gecq0gxmheI

Comment: Yes I asked that question... they answered there before :p